# Saxophone articulation - interpreting symbols

Tags: saxophone, articulation

I have a number of pieces that feature the following articulation symbols (highlighted in red; last bar of Andy Firth's "The Bullfrog Bounce"):

[image: Articulation example]

I've asked my teacher how to play them, but his explanations were very vague. Since I do not know even what they're called, it is impossible for me to find any materials. The articles I've discovered do not feature either symbol.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcato

Comment: https://www.dolmetsch.com/musictheory21.htm#accent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`∧` (Italian "martellato") is a symbol used to denote a strong accent, usually a rhythmic thrust followed by a decay of the sound. `>` (Italian "marcato") is a "lighter" version of the same accent. In jazz scores, like the one in the question, it usually also means that the note is supposed to be played for approximately ​2⁄3 of its normal duration.

With the saxophone, the effect can be achieved by adjusting the embouchure or introducing a drop in the jaw.

I'd like to thank [Your Uncle Bob](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/40114/your-uncle-bob) and [replete](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/48353/replete) for providing the links explaining those symbols.

Comment: Be aware that some people call the `^` a marcato, and `>` an accent. Just to make life confusing.

Comment: @endorph, thank you. It made the Wikipedia article more confusing indeed.

Comment: it doesn't matter how you call it, the meaning and interpretation is correct. There are lots of different spellings by different languages and in other countries or other styles.

Comment: Dolmetsch has  pretty good page on accents: https://www.dolmetsch.com/musictheory21.htm#accent

Comment: @Albrecht_Hügli it will matter the first time someone says "play that with an accent" and the OP only knows it as a marcato. So, I think it's a valid point.